# how to make edittext move from left to right or vice versa in animation type

Tags: android

i have done validation for edittext onclick of button and if it is empty will show a toast saying particular field empty and in addition want edittext to get it moved from left to right and vice versa as an animated form and will help to make app attractive Is it possible?? if so please help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create and Write following into anim/shake.xml:

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="10" android:duration="1000"
    android:interpolator="@anim/cycle_7" />
```

Create and Write following into anim/cycle_7.xml:

```
<cycleInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:cycles="7" />
```

now Use Animation class to animate any view by passing in argument. Call this method by passing any view

```
public void onShake(View v, String your_msg) {
    Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);
    findViewById(R.id.pw).startAnimation(shake);
    Toast.makeText(this, your_msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: this pw would be edittext or whatever on which i want to implement animation i hope so @Pratik

Comment: Yes you can use any view you want to shake it

Comment: Thnaks Very Much @pratik

Comment: Nice its help full to me.its better to shange colour also

Comment: is there any ways that I could increase the speed at which edittext shakes?

Comment: Yes decrease/increase the android:duration value in <translate/>

Comment: How to shake edit text two times?